# getting error "Call to a member function send() on null" while sending sms through Signalwire api using laravel

Tags: laravel, signalwire, signalwire-api

Using relay client api to send sms from Signalwire it gives an error message

> "Call to a member function send() on null" in file
> vendor\signalwire\signalwire\src\Relay\Connection.php

$this->_ws->send($msg->toJson());

I am using these code below

```
use SignalWire\Relay\Client;

$client = new Client(['project' =>'project_id','token' => 'token_id']);

$params = [
    'context' => 'office',
    'from' => '+1++++',
    'to' => '+1++++',
    'body' => 'Welcome at SignalWire!'
];

Log::info('Sending SMS..');

$client->messaging->send($params)->done( function ($sendResult){

    if ($sendResult->isSuccessful()) {
        Log::info('SMS queued successfully!');
        echo 'success';
      
    } else {
        Log::warning('Error sending SMS!');
        echo 'error';
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems ` $client->messaging` is null, check if your `$client` is having correct structure and have property called messaging.

Comment: I have followed these document of signalwire,as I checked I have used correct structure as per document.

https://docs.signalwire.com/reference/relay-sdk-php/v2/#api-reference-relay-client-constructor

https://docs.signalwire.com/reference/relay-sdk-php/v2/#api-reference-relay-messaging-methods-send

This error is coming on websockets which used in signalwire package/api

Comment: what is the output of $client? ```dd($client)```

Comment: ^ SignalWire\Relay\Client {#475 ▼
  +uuid: "f7822654-6823-4543-bc37-b314365dcf4b"
  +host: "relay.signalwire.com"
  +project: "My project id"
  +token: "my token no"
  +sessionid: null
  +nodeid: null
  +connection: SignalWire\Relay\Connection {#494 ▶}
  +eventLoop: React\EventLoop\StreamSelectLoop {#489 ▶}
  +relayProtocol: null
  +signature: null
  +contexts: []
  #_calling: null
  #_tasking: null
  #_messaging: null
  -_autoReconnect: true
  -_loopIsRunning: false
  -_idle: false
  -_executeQueue: []
  -_subscriptions: []
  -_reconnectTimer: null

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler for sending messages.

```
$client->on('signalwire.ready', function($client) use ($params){
     $client->messaging->send($params)->done( function ($sendResult)       
       if ($sendResult->isSuccessful()) {
         echo "Message ID: " . $sendResult->getMessageId();
       } else {
         echo 'error';
       }
     });
})->on('signalwire.error', function(\Exception $error) {
    echo "Error";
});
```

`signalwire.ready` method indicates that the session has been established and all other methods can now be used.

So with the use of this event handler, you can resolve the bug "Call to a member function send() on null" in the file.